# Correct solution to get only one relation item based on condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, eloquent

For a product I want to get the active coupon. There can be only one active coupon at one time.

My product-Modal looks something like this:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public $table_name = 'products';

    protected $hidden = [
        'coupons',
    ];

    public function coupons() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Coupon', 'dish_id');
    }

    public function activeCoupons() {
        $instance = $this->hasMany('App\Models\Coupon', 'dish_id');
        $instance->getQuery()->where('start', '<', new \DateTime());
        $instance->getQuery()->where('end', '>', new \DateTime());
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

I am delivering the products to the app with a JSON-API.

After fetching the data from the database I am doing something very ugly now:

```
$product['coupon'] = $product->activeCoupons[0];
```

I am doing this, because I don't want to return an array of activeCoupons in my JSON. I want to return the active coupon or null.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```
$product['coupon'] = $product->activeCoupons()->first();
```

Or even using `limit`. The idea is:

```
public function activeCoupons() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Coupon', 'dish_id');
                ->where('start', '<', new \DateTime());
                ->where('end', '>', new \DateTime())
                ->limit(1);
}
```

Comment: With the first one I still have to iterate each item after fetching it, what is not very clean I think.. And with the second approach I still get an array.. In the array is only one item but it's still an array in JSON...

Comment: So, unfortunately I do not understand what you need as result.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what your asking for from your reply to Laerte

```
 public function firstActiveCoupon() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Coupon', 'dish_id')
         ->where('start', '<', new \DateTime())
         ->where('end', '>', new \DateTime());
    }
```